# Prove that if a given sequence converges to a limit L then $L=\alpha$ or $L=\beta$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have this sequence $$a_1=c,(\alpha+\beta)a_{n+1}=a_n^2+\alpha\beta$$
And I need to show that if it converges to a limit $L$ then $L=\alpha$ or $L=\beta$.

I'm not sure how to do this. I've been trying to algebraically manipulate the definition of a limit
$$a_n\rightarrow L \iff \forall\epsilon>0 \exists N\in\mathbb{N}: \ \forall n\geq N |a_n-L|<e$$
But am not really getting anywhere.

Comment: Can you see that $a_n \to L$ implies that $(\alpha+\beta)L=L^2+\alpha\beta$ ?

Comment: The trick that Martin is referring to is that you just take the limit on both sides of your recurrence relation. (To do this, you need to assume the limit exists in the first place.)

Comment: Oh my god okay I got it now, I'm still new to AOL and didn't spot that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hmmmm I seem to recognise this problem sheet ; )